# Do Array2Ds print incorrectly in F#?

Tags: f#

I execute the following, expecting to see 3 rows and 4 columns:

```
let my2DArray = Array2D.init 3 4 (fun x y -> (x,y))
```

But when I run this in the interactive window, the output is:

```
val my2DArray : (int * int) [,] = [[(0, 0); (0, 1); (0, 2); (0, 3)]
                                   [(1, 0); (1, 1); (1, 2); (1, 3)]
                                   [(2, 0); (2, 1); (2, 2); (2, 3)]]
```

Aren't the rows and columns transposed? I would expect there to be three rows and four columns. It works as expected in memory:

```
> my2DArray.[2,0];;
val it : int * int = (2, 0)
```

Am I looking at or thinking about this wrong?

Comment: > I would expect there to be three rows and four columns. It works as expected in memory:  
Isn't that what you get from print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed printing 3 rows and 4 columns. Columns are vertical, rows are horizontal.

[image]

Comment: Uh, yeah, I was thinking about it wrong, because even though I CLAIMED I expected 3 rows and 4 columns, I expected 4 rows and 3 columns  :P  Thanks, sometimes one just needs a conk on the head